# How to get a loaded data from view back to controller to be reused on another function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am studying CRUDS in codeigniter and have been successful in displaying data from a database and inserting data in the database. I am not sure where I went wrong here but I need to reuse the ID I loaded in the view page to edit it in the database, I loaded the data using the code below, (its part of a foreach loop), i was ask to edit the question

```
<div class="gbItem">
                    <a href="#"></a>
<a href="#" class="pull-left">
                      <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/public/img/profile.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="gbItemBody clearfix">
                      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $value->user_id  ;?>">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle gbDeactivate"></i>
                        <a><strong>
                          <?php echo $value->user_firstname;?>
                          <?php echo $value->user_lastname;?>
                        </strong></a>
                        <br>                            
                          <strong>
                            Campaign 1
                          </strong>                            
                      </div>  
                      <div class="pull-right">
                        <span class="gbDeactivate pull-right">Idle</span><br>
                        <span class="pull-right">Skill Level 4</span>                           
                      </div>              
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I need this back in the controller to be used in a function named

```
public function update()
{
$user['user_name'] = $this->users_model->get_by_id("i want it here");
//codes here
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem :

```
public function update()
{
$id = $this->input->post('user_id');
$user['user_name'] = $this->users_model->get_by_id($id);
//codes here
}
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for me since multiple user_id is being stored to $id, the code `<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $value->user_id  ;?>">` is part of a for each and about 20 user_id are being loaded...

Comment: i have edited the question to show the whole div, i just need the id of the clicked <div class="gbitem">

Comment: I am sorry, i think the mistake is with the way I asked the question, this code works for my other codeigniter project (simple crud), but is not with the more visually appealing one, ill just post another question and delete this question after an hour...

Comment: No need to delete this question.

Answer (score -1):

Friend i wil help you
In controller,when adding data,use this $this->insert_id();//that wil help you to get inserted id.

```
$insert=$this->tender_model->form_insert($data);
 $id = $this->db->insert_id();

//then pass this id to view page
```

like this

```
$this->load->view('moderator/managetender',$id);
```

In view page we can give link for edit action and can pass $id along with that function
In View

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'moderator/Tender/editdetails/'.$id?>"><button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit Details</button></a>
```

Comment: im sorry, i am having a hard time explaining my problem, but ill just open a new question and delete this after an hour...